# Show user name on Google Apps form

Tags: google-workspace, google-forms, username

In Google Apps I can choose to *Automatically collect respondent's username*.

How do I display the username or First Name and/or Last Name on the subsequent form?

I'd like the form to read something like: "Hi Bob, thanks for taking our survey."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add any elements that are not available in the form builder, so you cannot control how the respondent's username is displayed.

But the the username *is* displayed to the user filling in your form, **if you're using Google Apps for Business**. Make sure the options *Require [domain name] login to view this form* and *Automatically collect respondent's [domain name] username* are checked:

[image: Require (domain name) login to view this form / Automatically collect respondent's (domain name) username]

The end user will see this on the top of the form:

[image: Your username (username) will be recorded when you submit this form. Not (username)? Sign out.]